# Bookshelf JS accessing the value of a model's idAttribute property

Tags: javascript, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I am having trouble accessing an id within a model.  I know that a model can have a property `idAttribute` which I have defined.  My problem is I want to use the id of my model to make a query, but I don't know how.  I have read over the bookshelfJS docs, but to no avail.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  My code looks something like this:

```
let Recipe = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'recipes',
  idAttribute: 'id',
  visible: ['name', 'description', 'prep_time', 'cook_time', 'notes', 
  'image_url', 'ingredients', 'instructions', 'tags', 'votes'],
  hasTimestamps: true,


  votes: function() {
    // return this.hasMany(RecipeVote);
    bookshelf.knex('recipes_votes')
    .sum('vote')
    .where('recipe_id', `I WANT MY MODELS ID HERE`)
    .groupBy('recipe_id')
    .then(function (result) {
      // cb(null, sum)
      console.log('SUM:', result[0].sum);
      return result[0].sum;
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      // cb(err)
      console.log('THERE WAS AN ERROR:', err);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: have you tried doing `this.idAttribute` ?

Comment: or just `this.id`?

Answer (score 2):

I think u can access the id attribute the following way:

`this.attributes.id`

OR

`this.get('id')`

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  Thank you.  This works.  Bookshelf can be a bit confusing and the documentation seems a bit lackluster, but that could just be my inexperience.